# Spring roo ldap authentication and database authorization

Tags: spring-roo

I have a **Sping roo** applicaiton and I want to apply authentication through LDAP and authorization on (e.g. read only/ admin) screens through database tables User/UserRole. Can someone point me to a sample application ?

I have gone through documentation on http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/beginning.html for Securing the Application. However I am looking for ldap and database together.

Thanks
Amber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a tutorial with the LDAP piece [here](http://blogs.sourceallies.com/2009/12/spring-roo-sample-app-tutorial-part-1/)

For the Authorization piece, you can solve that by implementing a UserDetailService (the piece that looks up a users authorization in a database and assigns it, allowing you to put fences around pieces of your application), and adding it to your authentication provider

Here's another (probably better) example of LDAP [authentication](https://github.com/krimple/spring-roo-in-action-examples/blob/master/chapter-08-security/coursemanager-security/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-security.xml)

Answer (score 0):

gvNIX includes the Typical Security addon that setups Spring Security and adds default security settings to your project. Then you only have to customize it using Spring Security docs and tutorial.

Take a look at http://code.google.com/p/gvnix/wiki/TypicalSecurity